# The handler in click button keeps adding everytime I refresh my page

Tags: jquery

I use jquery to bind a click event in my link element and binding a handler. But every time I refresh the page the registration of the handler in my link element keeps adding. Like for example, in a new load page, only one handler registered in the click but when I click the link again, it it will add another handler.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
  $("#blck").slideToggle("fast", function(){
  });
});
```

Comment: Are there any frames involved? I'm just wondering if the script is being reloaded in some way (check your net panel)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine.  You must be withholding vital information:

http://jsfiddle.net/2A78D/